# Iterate in reverse order through the parameter-pack of a variadic template function

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, tail-recursion

I'm trying to iterate in reverse order through the parameter-pack of a variadic template function. My idea was to use tail recursion and a specialized "empty" template function to stop the recursion:

```
#include <iostream>

template<>
void f() {}

template<int H, int... T>
void f()
{
    f<T...>();
    std::cout << H << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    f<1,2,3,4,5>();

    return 0;
}
```

However the code above does not compile:

> ```
> p.cc:25:8: error: ‘f’ is not a template function
>  void f() {}
>         ^
> p.cc: In instantiation of ‘void f() [with int H = 5; int ...T = {}]’:
> p.cc:30:12:   recursively required from ‘void f() [with int H = 2; int ...T = {3, 4, 5}]’
> p.cc:30:12:   required from ‘void f() [with int H = 1; int ...T = {2, 3, 4, 5}]’
> p.cc:36:18:   required from here
> p.cc:30:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘f()’
>      f<T...>();
>             ^
> p.cc:28:6: note: candidate: template<int H, int ...T> void f()
>  void f()
>       ^
> p.cc:28:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> p.cc:30:12: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘H’
>      f<T...>();
> ```

I *feel* this is just a syntax error -- but I'm unable to find the solution by myself. Any idea?

Comment: `template<>void f() {}` is not a valid primary template definition. A template cannot have an empty set of parameters. It is a valid syntax for a template specialisation, but there is no template in scope to specialise.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense--but I'm still unable to compile properly. I probably made a second mistake...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you should provide, well, template declaration before specializations:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename...> void f();

template<>
void f() {}

template<int H, int... T>
void f()
{
    f<T...>();
    std::cout << H << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    f<1,2,3,42,5>();

    return 0;
}
```

Here we go: https://ideone.com/TZal7p

Comment: Thanks, but could you provide the complete solution? I think I understand what you say, but somehow, I'm still unable to compile properly my short example code :/

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you believe it: I had to use `diff` to compare my code with yours to finally find I declared `template<typename...> f();` -- that is with the `void` return type missing :D.